# Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a map of sets, and let {$X_i$}$_{i\in I}$ be an indexed collection of subsets of A.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $f(\cap_{i\in I}X_i)\subset\cap_{i\in I}f(X_i)$

From a second year calculus course. Have only done Basic Set Theory and Injective/Surjective functions. I'm thinking the proof has something to do with the injectivity of $f(\cap_{i\in I}X_i)$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is a general fact; you do not need $f$ to be injective. Have you tried unpacking definitions? This might look kind of scary if you haven't done many proofs before, but you will be surprised by how little work you have to do. Take $y\in f(\bigcap X_i)$. Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in\bigcap X_i$. Then...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$
X\subset Y\implies f(X)\subset f(Y)
$$
Also for any $i\in I$, there is
$$
\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\subset X_i
$$
Thus for any $i\in I$, we have
$$
f\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right)\subset f(X_i)\tag1
$$
Since $(1)$ holds for any $i\in I$
$$
f\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right)\subset \bigcap_{i\in I}f(X_i)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be clear that if $y\in f (\cap_i X_i) $,  that is to say, $y =f (x)$ for some $x \in \cap_i X_i $, then $x \in X_i $ for all $X_i $ so $f (x) \in f (X_i) $ for all $f (X_i) $.  So $y = f (x) \in \cap_i (X_i) $ and therefore $f (\cap_i X_i) \subset \cap_i f (X_i) $.

That is clear.  What isn't clear is why it isn't an equality.

Consider $f(x)= \sin x $.  Let $X_i = [2i\pi, 2i\pi + 2\pi] $.  Then $f (X_i) = [-1,1] $ and $\cap_i f (X_i) =[-1,1] $.

But $\cap_i X_i = \emptyset $ and $f (\emptyset) = \emptyset $.

So $f (\cap_i X_i) = \emptyset \subsetneq [-1,1] = \cap_i f (X_i) $.